# Python selenium - get values from p and span

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver

Let's say I have a code like this:

```
<div class="div1">
            <div class="div2">
            <div class="div3">X:  <span class="SpanX">ValueX</span></div>
            <p class="p_class">A: <span class="SpanA"> ValueA </span> </p>
            <p class="p_class_2">B: <span class="SpanB">ValueB</span></p>
            <p class="p_class">C: <span class="SpanA">ValueC</span></p>
            </div>
</div>
```

I would like to get a dictionary like `{X:ValueX, A:ValueA, B:ValueB, C:ValueC}`

I tried to get `driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class = "div1")` but what next?

How do I go deeper in the structure? How do I retrieve values of span nested in p ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XML your code I see the first text pair is inside `<div class="div3">` while all the other text pairs are inside `<p>` elements. So the common denominator here is that all these elements are immediate children of `<div class="div2">` element.
Now you can get the text value of the direct child elements and of the internal `span` elements.
You can get a list of "key" values, a list of "value" values and then zip them into a dictionary as following:

```py
keys = []
values = []
elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='div2']/*")
for element in elements:
    entire_text = element.text
    key = entire_text.split(" ")[0]
    keys.append(key)
elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='div2']/*/span")
for element in elements:
    value = element.text
    values.append(value)
dictionary = dict(zip(keys, values))
print(dictionary) #{X:ValueX, A:ValueA, B:ValueB, C:ValueC}
```

Answer (score 1):

Copy the xpath of each of the value you want to retrieve. You will find a pattern there and a simple loop can be used to iterate those elements.

For example, the xpaths of elements inside the tag might look like these:

```
- /html/body/div/div/p[1]/span
- /html/body/div/div/p[2]/span
- /html/body/div/div/p[3]/span
```

Following this pattern, you can use the following loop to extract your desired value:

```
for index in range(1,4):

    # concatenating the index values to iterate through the elements
    xpath_string = "/html/body/div/div/p[" + str(index) + "]/span"
  
    # catching that particular element using xpath
    element = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath_string)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use beautifulsoup! It allows you to search for specific tags/ids/classes and then extract the text/links etc.

Here's the docs:
https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: They didn't ask for an alternate product. They asked how to do this in Selenium. If you're going to recommend a different product entirely, _at least_ demonstrate _how_ this specific task can be accomplished using it.